# Ansible - Replace " and \r\ in a variable

Tags: replace, ansible, escaping, jinja2, double-quotes

I want to replace the `"` and `\r\` from a variable content using Ansible.

I have the following data in a variable `result` thatI register the output to the variable from the previous task

```
curl -s -H \"Authorization: JWT eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJQytqQ0NBHuHO96csEQ\r\" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/talasecurityinc/?page_size=10000 | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'
```

In the above content I want to replace the `\` and `\r\` with null.

I have tried the below way but it doesn't work for me.

```
- set_fact: final_out="{{result | replace('\', "") | replace('\r\', '')}}"
```

The expected output is

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJQytqQ0NBHuHO96csEQ" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/talasecurityinc/?page_size=10000 | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'
```

The example playbook snippet would be helpful for me since I am new to ansible.

Comment: What is generating the `curl` command line?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping Hell....

I was not able to use `replace`, probably because I didn't try hard/smart enough. Meanwhile, in your specific case, you can achieve the expected result with a single `regex_replace` filter call so it was easier (and it worked right away :)).

I used yaml folded blocks (`>`) with white space control (`-`) to minimize the escape hassle. If you don't know what that is, have a look at a yaml doc ([learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) is my favorite one)

Note that the remaining backslashes in the last result below are added by ansible to escape the double quotes in the output.

```
---
- name: Escape chars
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test: >-
      curl -s -H \"Authorization: JWT eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJQytqQ0NBHuHO96csEQ\r\"
      https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/talasecurityinc/?page_size=10000
      | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'

  tasks:
    - name: Show the untouched var
      debug:
        var: test

    - name: Escape the var as intended
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ test | regex_replace('\\r?\\?', '') }}
```

which results in

```sh
PLAY [Escape chars] ********************************************************************

TASK [Show the untouched var] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test": "curl -s -H \\\"Authorization: JWT eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJQytqQ0NBHuHO96csEQ\\r\\\" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/talasecurityinc/?page_size=10000 | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'"
}

TASK [Escape the var as intended] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "curl -s -H \"Authorization: JWT eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJQytqQ0NBHuHO96csEQ\" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/talasecurityinc/?page_size=10000 | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```